Best way for users to report conditions for different segments of the same road
I have developed a site that tracks the status of backcountry roads for drivers where users can view or report on the conditions of the roads they drive. At the moment report functionality is quite simple. A user adds the date they drove the road, a description + photos and finally they can add a general condition rating. E.g. Good Condition, Impassible, Degraded and so on.
These conditions ratings are often too simplified for long backcountry roads. For example a road may be in good condition for the first 10 kilometers and then degrade after. I am short for ideas on how to give users the ability to report multiple conditions on a road segment however.
The form currently looks like so:

One idea I had was to user a slider and have the user add a report for a given length of road. They could use the slider to indicate what length of road the condition applies for. Then they can add another condition for a different segment. Example:

I'm unfortunately more versed on the backend/coding side of things and less so on what users might like as an easy to use form for this type of information. Any insights are greatly appreciated.
For some context here's what the end result would look like on the map:


I find the second option with the route sections more intuitive, but I would simplify the functionality

Apply the status at the time of selecting the action point, this implies eliminating the "Add Rating" step.
Mark the percentage of action
Represent the color graph of the states in the slider that will then be repeated in the image



Wow, this is really clever! Thank you! I never would have thought of that.
